excel - how to pick the whole row using randbetween
I'm trying to pick a random row from my dataset shown below.
I'm wanting to pick out 2 rows from the list at random, with column C being the column that is randomized and column D to match with the value show in column C.
Like this:

Dotty Davies | Kay, Changing Ends 1x03
Lucas Royalty | Young Jonah, 9-1-1 5x17

currently I'm using this formula
   =INDEX(C1:D10,RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS(C1:C10)),1)
   =INDEX(D1:E10,RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS(D1:D10)),1)

Which is showing this:

Dotty Davies | Redbird, Batwheels 2x10
Lucas Royalty | Self, Sesame Street

Column C appears to be working, however Column D isn't matching up with the original value in the row pulled from Column C
How do I do this correctly using Excel???





C
D




Kylee Levien
Teen Autumn, Outer Range 2x06


Crew Kingston Miskel
Redbird, Batwheels 2x10


Lucas Royalty
Young Jonah, 9-1-1 5x17


Kiefer O'Reilly
Alexi Zinman, Alert: Missing Persons Unit 2x08


Oliver Savell
Young Alan Carr, Changing Ends 1x03


Dotty Davies
Kay, Changing Ends 1x03


Nariyah Ann SimpsonBoushee
Self, Sesame Street


Aiden Stoxx
Tayo Abiola, The Good Doctor 7x08


Charlie Storey
Young Sedona Jones, Sullivan's Crossing 2x02


Hannah Bos
Hannah Devlin, Dead Boy Detectives 1x03




Try using the following formula:


=TAKE(SORTBY(C1:D10,RANDARRAY(ROWS(C1:D10))),2)


Shown demo in web version of Excel!


Or,
=CHOOSEROWS(SORT(C1:D10,RANDARRAY(ROWS(C1:D10)),1),SEQUENCE(2))


Using Structured References aka Tables:
=CHOOSEROWS(SORT(Table1,RANDARRAY(ROWS(Table1)),1),SEQUENCE(2))



Perfect, thanks. I have one last question, if I was to add more rows e.g. C1:D15, can I dynamically change this or do I need to update the formula each time this happens?

@jenstar as you noticed Google sheets and Excel are different. You shouldn't tag Excel / Excel-formula. There's a Google Sheets tag

Pick Random Rows
Input Sheet TV Actors: Convert List to Excel Table

Select the list (including headers).
Hold down Ctrl and press T and click OK.




Select any cell(s) in the table and select Table Design to rename it to e.g. TV_Actors.

Helper Sheet Hidden

In cell A2 enter the following spilling formula:
=SEQUENCE(ROWS(TV_Actors))


Hide it if preferable.



Formulas-->Defined Names-->Name Manager

Create the following names:

PickRandomRows
 =LAMBDA(data,rows,TAKE(SORTBY(data,RANDARRAY(ROWS(data))),rows))


TV_Actors_Rows
 =Hidden!A2#






Output Sheet Random


In cell A3, create a drop-down list using Data-->Data Tools-->Data Validation.

Select List and use the following formula:
=TV_Actors_Rows







In cell A5 enter the following spilling formula:
=TV_Actors[#Headers]


In cell A6 enter the following spilling formula:
=PickRandomRows(TV_Actors,A3)

You can use the PickRandomRows (Lambda) function anywhere in your workbook.

Apply formatting as you see fit.

Play with it by selecting the number of rows in cell A3 and pressing F9 to recalculate.


